# How to get STDEV of Prices over time, based on ID and Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm testing the code below and I'm seeing some weird results.

```
INSERT INTO VOL_TABLE
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ID, AsOfDate, 
    STDEV(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY  AsOfDate ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) As Vol30Days,
    STDEV(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY  AsOfDate ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC ROWS BETWEEN 60 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) As Vol60Days,
    STDEV(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY  AsOfDate ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC ROWS BETWEEN 90 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) As Vol90Days
FROM Price_Final
Where LEN(ID) > 1
    And AsOfDate Is Not Null) x
```

My results come back like this.

```
ID  AsOfDate    Vol30Days   Vol60Days   Vol90Days
982781  7/7/2019    NULL        NULL        NULL
982781  7/8/2019    4.65        4.65        4.65
982781  7/9/2019    7.71        7.71        7.71
982781  7/10/2019   8.48        8.48        8.48
982781  7/11/2019   8.66        8.66        8.66
982781  7/12/2019   NULL        NULL        NULL
982781  7/13/2019   8.71        8.71        8.71
982781  7/14/2019   7.4         7.4         7.4
982781  7/16/2019   4.58        4.58        4.58
```

Going backwards in time, there shouldn't be any nulls, until I get back to 30, 60, and 90 days from the start.  Also the numbers looks totally wrong.  If I do the same thing in Excel I get this.

```
ID      Price   AsOfDate    30DayVol    60DayVol    90DayVol
982781  117.663 7/6/2019    1.980175065 1.888013878 1.710750597
982781  117.565 7/7/2019    1.946177746 1.869405011 1.705288536
982781  119.323 7/8/2019    1.948570344 1.887679003 1.716398812
982781  119.382 7/9/2019    1.951828758 1.890564357 1.728941808
982781  119.508 7/10/2019   1.953349544 1.897933537 1.742350047
982781  119.604 7/11/2019   1.953751571 1.908002077 1.756114814
982781  115.665 7/12/2019   1.94839382  1.915523148 1.759252528
982781  117.786 7/13/2019   1.916545144 1.910871414 1.754831661
982781  117.943 7/14/2019   1.876038031 1.899600919 1.754410265
982781  115.397 7/16/2019   1.863831084 1.907504139 1.756518442
```

I'm guessing the problem is coming from the PARTITION BY, but I'm not sure.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're partitioning and ordering by the same column. That doesn't seem right as the order wouldn't be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `partition by` create a separate grouping for each `asofdate`.  That means there is only one date in the grouping and the `order by` is irrelevant.

I am guessing that you really want the `order by`.  And if you want the previous  days, do not use `DESC` for the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT ID, AsOfDate, 
       STDEV(Price) OVER (ORDER BY AsOfDate ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) As Vol30Days,
       STDEV(Price) OVER (ORDER BY AsOfDate ROWS BETWEEN 60 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) As Vol60Days,
       STDEV(Price) OVER (ORDER BY AsOfDate ROWS BETWEEN 90 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) As Vol90Days
FROM Price_Final
WHERE LEN(ID) > 1;
```

This assumes that you have one price per day in the data.  If you have multiple products (as suggested by the `id`), you might really want `PARTITION BY id ORDER BY AsOfDate`).

Comment: I see your point, and it makes sense now.  However, with this logic, I still get nulls for Vol30Days.  That doesn't seem right.  If all Prices are filled in, shouldn't all Vol30Days be filled in?

Comment: @Ash . . . Not for the first couple of days.

Comment: All set now.  Thanks.